# Classic ASP error in Windows Server 2012 / IIS8

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I recently had to migrate an (inherited) old Classic ASP VBScript reporting website from a windows server 2003 to windows server 2012.

After messing about with the AppPool to make it use 32bit mode, and also set up parent paths, I've been able to get the application to work.

However, the following page is currently throwing this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: ''

/Dashboard/modules/Monthly_Report/footfall/Save_Session_Variables_Stock.asp, line 69
```

The code behind the page is

```
<!--#include file="../../../../Connections/Dashboard_Connection.asp" -->
<%
Session.LCID=2057
'Session("strMonthly_Site")=trim(request("select_site"))
''xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
'Set the search screen variables to be nothing
Session("strCategory_Lookup")=""
Session("strSearch_String")=""

'*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
'Get the market code based on the site
'*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
DIM rsGet_Market
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open strConnection

'Get the Site Level_Code
Session("SITE_LVL") = MID(Session("strMonthly_Site"),INSTR(Session("strMonthly_Site"),",")+ 1, 2)
Session("SITE_LVL_CODE") = LEFT(Session("strMonthly_Site"),INSTR(Session("strMonthly_Site"),",")-1)

SELECT CASE CINT(Session("SITE_LVL"))

CASE 1 'Site

strQuery = "SELECT SITE_MARKET.MARKET_CODE, SITE_MARKET.MARKET_TEXT, SITE_ZONE.ZONE_CODE, SITE_ZONE.ZONE_TEXT, SITE_AREA.AREA_CODE, SITE_AREA.AREA_TEXT, SITE.SITE_CODE, SITE.SITE_TEXT " & _
            "FROM SITE_REGION INNER JOIN SITE_MARKET ON SITE_REGION.REGION_CODE = SITE_MARKET.REGION_CODE INNER JOIN SITE INNER JOIN SITE_AREA ON SITE.AREA_CODE = SITE_AREA.AREA_CODE " & _
            "INNER JOIN SITE_ZONE ON SITE_AREA.ZONE_CODE = SITE_ZONE.ZONE_CODE ON SITE_MARKET.MARKET_CODE = SITE_ZONE.MARKET_CODE " & _ 
            "WHERE SITE.SITE_CODE = '" & Session("SITE_LVL_CODE") & "'"

Set rsGet_Market = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsGet_Market.Open strQuery, objConn

Session("Market_Market_Code") = rsGet_Market("MARKET_CODE") & " - " & rsGet_Market("MARKET_TEXT")
Session("Market_Zone_Code") = rsGet_Market("ZONE_CODE") & " - " & rsGet_Market("ZONE_TEXT")
Session("Market_Area_Code") = rsGet_Market("AREA_CODE") & " - " & rsGet_Market("AREA_TEXT")
Session("Market_Site_Code") = rsGet_Market("SITE_CODE") & " - " & rsGet_Market("SITE_TEXT")
Session("MARKET_CODE") = rsGet_Market("MARKET_CODE")

Session("Market_Market_Code1") = rsGet_Market("MARKET_TEXT")
Session("Market_Zone_Code1") = rsGet_Market("ZONE_TEXT")
Session("Market_Area_Code1") = rsGet_Market("AREA_TEXT")
Session("Market_Site_Code1") = rsGet_Market("SITE_CODE") & " - " & rsGet_Market("SITE_TEXT")
Session("Table_Lvl_Label") = "Shop"

CASE 4 'Market

strQuery = "SELECT SITE_MARKET.MARKET_CODE, SITE_MARKET.MARKET_TEXT, SITE_ZONE.ZONE_CODE, SITE_ZONE.ZONE_TEXT, SITE_AREA.AREA_CODE, SITE_AREA.AREA_TEXT, SITE.SITE_CODE, SITE.SITE_TEXT " & _
            "FROM SITE_REGION INNER JOIN SITE_MARKET ON SITE_REGION.REGION_CODE = SITE_MARKET.REGION_CODE INNER JOIN SITE INNER JOIN SITE_AREA ON SITE.AREA_CODE = SITE_AREA.AREA_CODE " & _
            "INNER JOIN SITE_ZONE ON SITE_AREA.ZONE_CODE = SITE_ZONE.ZONE_CODE ON SITE_MARKET.MARKET_CODE = SITE_ZONE.MARKET_CODE " & _ 
            "WHERE SITE_MARKET.MARKET_CODE = '" & Session("SITE_LVL_CODE") & "'"

Set rsGet_Market = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsGet_Market.Open strQuery, objConn

Session("Market_Market_Code") = rsGet_Market("MARKET_CODE") & " - " & rsGet_Market("MARKET_TEXT")
Session("Market_Zone_Code") = "N/A"
Session("Market_Area_Code") = "N/A"
Session("Market_Site_Code") = "N/A"
Session("MARKET_CODE") = rsGet_Market("MARKET_CODE")

Session("Market_Market_Code1") = rsGet_Market("MARKET_TEXT")
Session("Market_Zone_Code1") = "N/A"
Session("Market_Area_Code1") = "N/A"
Session("Market_Site_Code1") = "N/A"
Session("Table_Lvl_Label") = "Market"

END SELECT

rsGet_Market.close
objConn.Close
set rsGet_Market= Nothing
set objConn= Nothing
response.redirect "Footfall_Report.asp"
%>
```

When tracing the SQL query, I can execute the same SELECT without any visible issues.

Would anyone have any ideas as to why this could be failing?

Comment: in most cases, when you use include directive, line number is incorrect. if you are not on production server, can you put STOP statement inside ASP code, and find exact line where this error happen?

Comment: Thanks Zam - putting STOP any where in the file points to line 71:

`set rsGet_Market= Nothing`

Comment: Correction, line 71 is `rsGet_Market.close`

Comment: can you do a `response.write Session("SITE_LVL")` before the `select case` and see what it contains? looks like it is not hitting any of the `case` s

Comment: I'm getting a value of "2" which is correct. If I switch between a `site` and a `market` on the `site` is working.

Comment: The error is because `rsGet_Market` is only instantiated on `Case 1` and `Case 4` so any other value of `CINT(Session("SITE_LVL"))` like `1` or `2` say will not instantiate `rsGet_Market` so there will not be a valid object for `Close()` to be executed on hence `Object required: ''`. If you are going to write it like that place `rsGet_Market.close` inside each of your case statements so it doesn't try to close it when it hasn't been instantiated.

Comment: Rob, it looks like this has been answered... have you marked an Answer as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into how to structure your code etc, it is a simple enough fix.

```vb
SELECT CASE CINT(Session("SITE_LVL"))
CASE 1 'Site

    'Recordset instantiated here
    Set rsGet_Market = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsGet_Market.Open strQuery, objConn

    'Lots of fluff here removed to emphasize the point
    '...

    'Close Recordset inside the Case statement
    rsGet_Market.close

CASE 4 'Market

    'Recordset instantiated here
    Set rsGet_Market = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsGet_Market.Open strQuery, objConn

    'Lots of fluff here removed to emphasize the point
    '...

    'Close Recordset inside the Case statement
    rsGet_Market.close

END SELECT

'Don't close rsGet_Market here as it might not exist and cause an error.
objConn.Close
```

By moving the `rsGet_Market.close` inside the Case statement it will only be called when there is a corresponding `ADODB.Recordset` in the `rstGet_Market` object.

> You can't Close a Recordset that never exists in the first place.

---

We could improve on this though by moving the instantiation outside of the Case statement to remove yet more duplication ([DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

```vb
'Recordset instantiated here
Set rsGet_Market = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

SELECT CASE CINT(Session("SITE_LVL"))
CASE 1 'Site

    'Recordset will be open if data is returned.
    rsGet_Market.Open strQuery, objConn

    'Lots of fluff here removed to emphasize the point
    '...

    'Close Recordset inside the Case statement
    rsGet_Market.close

CASE 4 'Market

    'Recordset will be open if data is returned.
    rsGet_Market.Open strQuery, objConn

    'Lots of fluff here removed to emphasize the point
    '...

    'Close Recordset inside the Case statement
    rsGet_Market.close

END SELECT

'Release Recordset object from memory
Set rsGet_Market = Nothing

'Don't close rsGet_Market here as it might not exist and cause an error.
objConn.Close
```

Comment: Personally I would also move `Set rsGet_Market = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Recordset")` before the case as well *([DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))* because you don't have an open `ADODB.Recordset` until `rsGet_Market.Open()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

> Correction, line 71 is rsGet_Market.close

OK. Let's take a look closer to your code.

You calling `rsGet_Market.close` always, but create it only for Case 1 and Case 4. Perhaps you have CINT(Session("SITE_LVL")) not equal to 1 and not equal to 4.

> but that doesn't generate any data.

Yes, but you always calling method (function) for not existing object (`Set` create it in your case for *rsGet_Market*). That why you have error **Object required: ''**

Comment: Correct, the code is only ever checking for type 4 or type 1. I can fake it to look at type 2, but that doesn't generate any data.

Comment: @RobSked Yes, but you always calling method (function) for not existing object (Set create it in your case for rsGet_Market). That why you have error Object required: ''